# Python dict of dict setting values missmatch

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi can anyone explain why we have the following behavior:

```
>>> k = [0.5, 1, 2]
>>> m = [0.5, 1, 2]
>>> dict1 = dict.fromkeys(k, dict.fromkeys(m, 0))
>>> dict1
{0.5: {0.5: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 1: {0.5: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 2: {0.5: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}}
>>> dict1[0.5][0.5]= 4.5
>>> dict1
{0.5: {0.5: 4.5, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 1: {0.5: 4.5, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 2: {0.5: 4.5, 1: 0, 2: 0}}


>>> dict2 = {0.5: {0.5: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 1: {0.5: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 2: {0.5: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}}
>>> dict2[0.5][0.5] = 4.5
>>> dict2
{0.5: {0.5: 4.5, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 1: {0.5: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 2: {0.5: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}}
```

so in the first case whenever I try to change a value of dict1 all the values  with the same second key are changing (e.g dict1[0.5][0.5]=4.5 will also change dict1[1][0.5] for some reason).

Comment: Because `dict.fromkeys(m, 0)` runs once, and then puts the same dictionary in every value for `dict.fromkeys(k, dict.fromkeys(m, 0))`. You can check this by doing `for dct in dict1: print id(dct)` they will all be the same `id`, eg. the same `object`

Comment: Only one sub-dictionary was ever created. What you have now is that dictionary itself accessible in multiple ways. `dict[0.5]` and `dict[1]` refer to the same dictionary (and not copies of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one sub-dictionary was ever created. What you have now is that dictionary itself accessible in multiple ways. 
`dict[0.5]` and `dict[1]` refer to the same dictionary (and not copies of it).

One way to achieve what you want to do is to use a dict comprehension:

```
dict1 = {k_outer: {k_inner:0 for k_inner in m} for k_outer in k}
```

This creates a new nested dict for each key, thereby avoiding the problem of them all accessing the same nested dict.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a good dupe target, although this general issue is common:

Because `dict.fromkeys(m, 0)` runs once when the function is called, and then puts the same dictionary in every value for `dict.fromkeys(k, dict.fromkeys(m, 0))`. You can check this by doing `for dct in dict1: print id(dict1[dct])` they will all be the same `id`, eg. the same object:

```
>>> for dct in dict1: print id(dict1[dct])
140401847695352
140401847695352
140401847695352
```

This happens because **parameters are only evaluated once, when the function is called**... so `dict.fromkeys` will put the same value (whatever that may be) in every key. It is equivalent to:

```
default_dct = dict.fromkeys(m, 0)
dict1 = dict.fromkeys(k, default_dct)
```

---

*Instead*, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict1 = {key: {ikey: 0 for ikey in m} for key in k}
```

or, via copying:

```
inner_dct = dict.fromkeys(m, 0)
dict1 = {}
for key in k:
    dict1[key] = inner_dct.copy()
```

Both of which yield different values:

```
>>>for dct in dict1: print id(dict1[dct])
140401847695352
140401847646200
140401847644240
```

Comment: Does that mean, it won't be possible to change a single key in dict1? That's a bummer.

Comment: @alDiablo it means you have to make nested dictionaries differently.

Comment: `dict.fromkeys` only to be used for quick read only dicts then?

Comment: I'll append my answer @alDiablo, the issue is **parameters are only evaluated once, when the function is called**... so `dict.fromkeys` will put the same value (whatever that may be) in every key.